# How to capture legendary Pokemon in unovaRPG?

Tags: unova-rpg

[UnovaRPG](https://m.unovarpg.com/login.php) is a browser based Pokémon game. It came in replacement for Pokémon Indigo and Pokémon Crater. The game offers many Pokémon to capture and fight with, but to my bad luck I have not been able to capture any legendary Pokémon.

**List of legendary Pokémon**

1. Articuno
2. Zapdos
3. Moltres
4. Celebi
5. Latios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing a lot of google search I came up with this:-

1. Master Ball:- Legendary Pokémon's can be only captured using Master Ball. All other balls will be wasted when used.
2. Elite Four:- Gym leaders from Elite Four has all the above mentioned Pokémon's. So the best way to capture one is by roaming around their room.
3. Custom Rooms:- Users can now create a room with custom Pokémon's available to be caught. Either create one room with legendary Pokémon's using UnovaRPG Currency or roam around someone else's room which already have the legendary Pokémon's.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a masterball to catch a legendary

Comment: Do you think you could add some more information to flesh out this answer? Maybe include some techniques you have found useful?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you don't need a Masterball to catch a Legendary. I have caught Articuno and Latios by Ultraballs. The trick is that you should have at least 5 to 10 Ultraballs and keep on throwing the balls until it gets caught, so it is like you should rapid fire the balls until the Legendary Pokemon gets caught. I also have a lvl 83 Xurkitree, lvl 40 Solgaleo, lvl 43 Kyurem and lvl 28 Rayquaza caught only by Ultraballs.